# Buildkit - amp test fails - incorrect response received

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

The setup ran smoothly until *amp test* which says:

```
$ amp test

Expect response: "response-code-SoYwxYyBvx"
Received incorrect response: "<?php
// This is a simple script which outputs "OK" if it
// executes correctly and connects properly to a database.

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
  || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
  || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
  ))
) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  exit('Connection must originate on localhost');
}

$config = require 'config.php';
$errors = array();

// ---------- Test HTTP inputs ----------

if (!isset($_REQUEST['exampleData']) || $_REQUEST['exampleData'] !== 'foozball') {
  $errors[]= "Error: Expected GET or POST value 'exampleData=foozball'";
}

// ---------- Test database ----------

try {
  $dbh = new \PDO($config['dsn'], $config['user'], $config['pass']);
  $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT 99 as value') as $row) {
    if ($row['value'] == 99) {
      // ok
    } else {
      $errors[] = "Error: Bad query result <br/>";
    }
  }
  $dbh = NULL;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $errors[] = "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}

// ---------- Test file permissions ----------

$dataFile = $config['dataDir'] . '/example.txt';
if (FALSE === file_put_contents($dataFile, "data")) {
  $errors[] = "Error: Failed to write $dataFile";
}
if (FALSE === unlink($dataFile)) {
  $errors[] = "Error: Failed to remove $dataFile";
}

// ---------- Wrap up ----------

if (empty($errors)) {
  echo "response-code-SoYwxYyBvx";
}
else {
  echo implode("\n", $errors);
  die();
}"
Tip: Try running "amp config" and/or restarting the webserver.
```

I believe I have set up `amp config` correctly. I even edited *apache2.conf* and included the line it asked to. But no matter how much I restart and test, it doesn't work.

My `amp config`:

```
mysql_dsn : mysql:civicrm:civicrm@localhost:8000
perm_type : linuxAcl
perm_user : www-data
httpd_type : apache24
```

And I included this line `Include /root/.amp/apache.d/*.conf` in *apache2.conf* file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was PHP files weren't being processed. I reinstalled PHP module using the following commands and it worked.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 php5
sudo apt-get remove --purge libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```