# Buildkit - amp test recieved incorrect response while connecting to a test application

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

I had successfully ran the buildkit till got this error while running amp test. It created the test application, created data directory, set up few ports

```
Create data directory:/home/***/.amp/canary/data/FivN1DBNa4c05mUoshFCNDn2dHMDc01I
AMP_URL='http://localhost:7979'
AMP_ROOT='/home/***/.amp/canary'
AMP_DB_DSN='mysql://canary_zcz0m:AfLQGc9SAf9Y8zno@127.0.0.1:3306/canary_zcz0m?new_link=true'
AMP_DB_USER='canary_zcz0m'
AMP_DB_PASS='AfLQGc9SAf9Y8zno'
AMP_DB_HOST='127.0.0.1'
AMP_DB_PORT='3306'
AMP_DB_NAME='canary_zcz0m'
AMP_DB_ARGS='-h 127.0.0.1 -u canary_zcz0m -pAfLQGc9SAf9Y8zno -P 3306 canary_zcz0m'

Connect to test application
Expect response: "response-code-8UnKuVzEwx"
```

and while connecting to test application it showed :

```
Received incorrect response: "Error: Failed to write /home/***/.amp/canary/data/FivN1DBNa4c05mUoshFCNDn2dHMDc01I/example.txt
Error: Failed to remove /home/***/.amp/canary/data/FivN1DBNa4c05mUoshFCNDn2dHMDc01I/example.txt"
```

I have followed the commands given here : https://buildkit.civicrm.org/#/tutorials.

And restarted the server many times.

Comment: Try this? http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10219/buildkit-amp-test-fails-incorrect-response-received

Comment: Hi, tried this already. Still showing the same error. Any more help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to the permission issue but I used another method for solving this.
At the time of amp config I chose [1] for the option perm_type, which sets the appropriate permissions according to linux.

Option: perm_type
Description: How to set permissions on data directories [none,custom,linuxAcl,osxAcl,worldWritable]. See https://github.com/totten/amp/blob/master/doc/perm.md

Default: none

Enter perm_type

1. [0] "none": Do not set any special permissions for the web user
2. [1] "linuxAcl": Set tight, inheritable permissions with Linux ACLs
   [setfacl] (recommended)
            In some distros+filesystems, this requires extra configuration.
            eg For Debian-based distros: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs
3. [2]"osxAcl": Set tight, inheritable permissions with OS X ACLs [chmod
   +a] (recommended)
4. [3] "custom": Set permissions with a custom command
5. [4] "worldWritable": Set loose, generic permissions [chmod
   1777] (discouraged)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error, setting up buildkit and then running `amp config` and `amp test` on Ubuntu 19.04.

What I figured out was that I too had initially chosen 0 for `perm_type` when running `amp config`.

I changed the `perm_type` value to `linuxAcl` and chose `www-data` as the web user.

Using those values then allowed me to successfully run `amp test`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to permission issues, so as you mentioned that you followed [civicrm-buldkit](https://buildkit.civicrm.org/#/tutorials) tutorials, now assuming that your buildkit is installed in `/opt/buildkit` directory I would suggest to change the permission of this directory by running the following code :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/buildkit
```

This command will recursively change the permission of the directory and enable all other users to create/modify/delete files and directories in it. But it is not advisable to do a 777 because of security reasons. If you are really concern about security then please look into changing the ownership of the files/directory or may be do a 755 instead with suitable arguments.

Hope it helps.